# Finding the torsion of the Neron Severi group in the first homology group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, complex-manifolds

Let X be a variety over $\mathbb C$. I will implicitly identify this with us complex analytification. Consider the exponential sequence:

$0 \to \mathbb Z \to \mathcal O_X \to \mathcal O_X^* \to 0$

If we consider the induced map on cohomology, we have the map :

$H^1(X,\mathcal O_X^*) \to H^2(X,\mathbb Z)$

where the image of the map is the Neron Severi group. By the universal coefficient theorem, the torsion in the $H^2$ term is the same as the torsion in $H_1(X, \mathbb Z) $.

Is there a more "organic" way to get this map from the torsion in $NS(X)$ to the first homology group?

For instance, is the following true :

In characteristic 0,the above implies that for a simply connected space or even a space with torsion free fundamental group, NS(X) is torsion free.

Does a corresponding result hold over finite characteristic? If a scheme (or variety) has trivial etale fundamental group, is the Neron Severi group necessarily torsion free?

Comment: Just some quick references: a possible answer to a more organic way to get this map is that via "cyclic covers", namely torsion line bundles give rise to etale covers, which give rise to elements of the etale fundamental group (see eg 'Compact Complex surfaces' by Barth et al). The same construction works in positive characteristic, but one has to be careful, eg $\operatorname{Pic}^0$ can be non-reduced, which along with the failure of Hodge duality leads to some rather strange phenomena (see eg Illusie's 'Complexe de de Rham-Witt et...').

Comment: How do you get an element of the fundamental group from a finite etale cover? @frank

Comment: What you say about the universal coefficients theorem is not quite correct: it only says that $Ext^1(T, \mathbb{Z})$ is isomorphic to the torsion in $H^2$, where $T$ is the torsion in $H_1$. The $Ext^1$ can be identified with $Hom(T, \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$, but there is no natural isomorphism with $T$ itself.